# entity framework Core generate Wrong migrigation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i have model class like below

```
public class DIMAuthOffice
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string UserNameManager { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentID))]
        public DIMAuthOffice OfficeParent { get; set; }
        public List<DIMAuthOffice> OfficeChilds { get; set; } = new List<DIMAuthOffice>();

        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserNameManager))]
        public DIMAuthUser UserManager { get; set; }
        public List<DIMAuthRole> DIMAuthRoles { get; set; } = new List<DIMAuthRole>();
        public List<DIMAuthRolePostOffice> DIMAuthRolePostOffices { get; set; } = new List<DIMAuthRolePostOffice>();

    }
```

but when i execute

> Add-Migration

the generated File is :

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "DIMAuthOffices",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    UserNameManager = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
                    ParentID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    UserManagerUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_DIMAuthOffices", x => x.ID);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_DIMAuthOffices_DIMAuthOffices_ParentID",
                        column: x => x.ParentID,
                        principalTable: "DIMAuthOffices",
                        principalColumn: "ID");
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_DIMAuthOffices_DIMAuthUsers_UserManagerUserName",
                        column: x => x.UserManagerUserName,
                        principalTable: "DIMAuthUsers",
                        principalColumn: "UserName");
                });
```

wrong line is :

> ParentID = table.Column(type: "int", nullable: false),

the generated File is Wrong and property ParentID set to nullable:false but this should be true ...
why ???

Comment: Try to declare `public DIMAuthOffice? OfficeParent { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't repro for me on EF Core 6.  eg

```
public class DIMAuthOffice
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string UserNameManager { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentID))]
    public DIMAuthOffice OfficeParent { get; set; }
    public List<DIMAuthOffice> OfficeChilds { get; set; } = new List<DIMAuthOffice>();


}
```

creates an initial migration of:

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "DIMAuthOffice",
        columns: table => new
        {
            ID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
            Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
            UserNameManager = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(50)", maxLength: 50, nullable: false),
            ParentID = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_DIMAuthOffice", x => x.ID);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_DIMAuthOffice_DIMAuthOffice_ParentID",
                column: x => x.ParentID,
                principalTable: "DIMAuthOffice",
                principalColumn: "ID");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I use FluentApi and writed this code in modelBuilder and fixed issue

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DIMAuthOffice>()
                .HasOne(q => q.OfficeParent)
                .WithMany(q => q.OfficeChilds)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```